# MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB Atlas database, but it's not working, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I've made sure I don't use illegal characters in my username and password, I've tried different connection strings. I've tried turning off my firewall.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const db = require("./keys").mongoURI;

mongoose.connect( db, { useNewUrlParser: true }  )
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB successfully connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; // process.env.port is Heroku's port if you choose to deploy the app there
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

**keys.js**

```
module.exports = {
    mongoURI: "mongodb+srv://username:password@mernauth-lksvn.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
};
```

I replaced the username and password in the connection string with the real username and password.

---

---

**EDIT: SOLUTION**
Even though I used both my IP address and the default IP address MongoDB Atlas suggested for me, neither worked. I guess I didn't have a valid IP address, so once I opened the database to all IP addresses, it worked!

Comment: Make sure your current IP is valid to connect to your mongodb atlas instance.

Comment: I used the IP address Atlas identified (as my current IP address)

Comment: Are you using the correct username and password?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I've double-checked many times

Comment: It was the IP address! (even though I used both my IP address and the IP address Atlas identified for me :/ that was the problem). Once I opened my database to all IP addresses, it worked!

Comment: For anyone having the same issue but none of the above resolved it, make sure that your environment variables aren't undefined